# On a downloaded copy of Highcharts are customizations disabled until licensed?

Tags: highcharts, difference

I have downloaded the latest and greatest copy of Highcharts and linked it into my project.

The bar chart could be created in it's basic form.

When I tried to tweak its colors, it wouldn't change the chart.

When I used the URL to link to https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js, instead of the files I downloaded to the project, the colors I was trying to use for series and background colors suddenly appeared.

A few questions:

- Is the downloaded version linked into my project crippled in anyway until licensing?
- I'm using ASP.NET, C#, and I have to manually say what dependencies get copied over whenever I include the highcharts.js. It's a REAL PITA. I fear that I might not have some resources set to copy over to the web directory, therefore causing an issue?
- Now Highcharts should really be vocal about something like this in the console.log, but seems to just sweep it under the rug. Is there any sort of 'diagnostic scope' I can look at to make sure it has access to all of the dependencies and it's not causing some *funkadelic* cascading snowball effect taking out huge swaths of needed code?

This has burnt up more valuable time than the licensing cost.

Comment: No, the library is not limited until licensed. I would check to make sure if you are using the CSS-styled version where all styling is handled in CSS or if you are using the version where the styling is set in the chart object (see here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css). Without seeing your code it is hard for us to tell what else it could be.

Comment: it should work without licensing. Can you post some code showing the problem ?